# Digit grouping with two decimal places in c#

Tags: c#, decimal

I want to display a number which is of double datatype in C#, in grouped digits and with two decimal places only if it contains a decimal no.

e.g. If there is 2000.4567 and 2000.45, it must be displayed as 2,000.45 and if it is 2000 then it will displayed as 2,000 (grouped but without decimal).

I have tried this and it is working fine for digit grouping but it rounds off the decimal no. to an integer value either by floor or ceil:

```
DimensionLength.ToString("#,##0")
```

DimensionLength is of type double.

Comment: `DimensionLength.ToString("N2");` is the shorthand form.

Comment: ToString("0.##") is fine but it doesn't allow digit grouping

Comment: ToString("N2"); also works fine but it displays 5 as 5.00 what is required if 5 then 5 and if 5.5 then 5.50

Comment: Did you try my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Code

```
 double s=123.345345;

           string str=string.Empty;

           str = s.ToString("#,0.##");

            MessageBox.Show(str);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are better off by creating your own custom condition

```
      double _inputval=2000.4567
      string _outputVal="";

       if ((_inputval % 1) == 0)
       {
           _outputVal = _inputval.ToString("#,##");
       }
       else
       {
           _outputVal = _inputval.ToString("N2");
       }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: How can I do this in Razor View ?